# XCode build strip for release

Tags: configuration, xcode4.2, release

I want to COMPLETELY remove anything related to debugging from my application. In XCode 4.2 I can  see several options for stripping release build off debug stuff.

Strip Debug Symbols During Copy,
Strip Linked Product,
Debug Information format,
and maybe there are some others

The "Quick Help" for these items provided by Apple seems vague for me. They looks as duplicating each other.
Can anyone explain the difference between these items?